# Vifm: Change file type assocation

Tags: vi, vifm

I've looked at the docs and still cannot figure out how to change a filetype to open with external editor. How can I make it so that pressing  in vifm on a `*.sql` files for example will use sublime3 external app instead of vim? I've already tried adding `filetype *.sql /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text` to my vifmrc file but it is still using default vim.

Answer (score 4):

Since patterns are not generally disjoint, the order in which `:filetype` commands are executed is important.  You probably put `filetype *.sql /opt/sublime_text_3` after `filetype * ...`, which catches everything and thus should be the last.

You can verify which application will be run for an sql file by running:

```
:filetype a.sql
```

A menu will pop-up showing list of applications vifm will try in top-down order.